# Using Python Jenkins I add new parameter to xml file and it do not update the configuration

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the Python Jenkins library to modify the xml configuration and create new parameters.

Once I upload the configuration to the job it look like similar to another parameters but it don't became in a job configuration.

How I can update the configuration from the .xml file?

**EDITED**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import jenkins

def add_param(config):
    """
    Recibe jpb config and add a new parameter.
    :param config: job configuration
    :type config: yaml
    :type return: str
    """
    snippet = """<hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>Testing</name>
          <description/>
          <defaultValue>Value</defaultValue>
          <trim>false</trim>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        """
    config_soup = BeautifulSoup(config, "xml")
        
    new_parameters = BeautifulSoup(snippet, 'lxml')
    config_soup.select_one('parameterDefinitions').append(new_parameters.body.next)
    
    return str(config_soup)



server = jenkins.Jenkins('***', username='****', password='**')

config = server.get_job_config('handling_with_python')

server.reconfig_job('handling_with_python', add_param(config))
```

Comment: It's not clear which file you are updating or how the update in deployed. Do you mean you try to modify the job's `config.xml` from within the job itself?

Comment: Hi! Please provide some context of your problem, show your research effort and code attempt
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Now I added the code that I'm using :)

Answer (score 0):

> `new_parameters = BeautifulSoup(snippet, 'lxml')`

The `lxml` parser turned my tags to lower case and it broke everything.

Comment: This doesn't reveal how you solved it.